# Sibling network using data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I would like to create a sibship network using `data.table`.

My data looks like this

```
indata <-
structure(list(id = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L), fid = c(NA, 
9L, 1L, 1L, 7L, 5L, 5L, 5L), mid = c(0L, NA, 2L, 2L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 8L)), .Names = c("id", "fid", "mid"), class = "data.frame", row.names = 
c(NA, -8L))
```

which is

```
  id fid mid
1  1  NA   0
2  2   9  NA
3  3   1   2
4  4   1   2
5 12   7   6
6 13   5   6
7 14   5   6
8 15   5   8
```

The three columns represent id, id of the father and id of the mother, respectively. `0` or `NA` means not available. Thus, in the data above person 3 and 4 are full siblings (they both have father `1` and mother `2`), while 12 and 13 are half siblings (they have different fathers but the same mum, `6`).

For each row in the data frame I would like a list of the person's siblings (let us just consider half siblings to start with). My ideal end result would be

```
  id fid mid sibs
1  1  NA   0 NA
2  2   9  NA NA
3  3   1   2 4
4  4   1   2 3
5 12   7   6 13, 14
6 13   5   6 12, 14, 15
7 14   5   6 12, 13, 15
8 15   5   8 13, 14
```

where the last column, `sibs`, is a list or vector (and it does not have to be part of the dataset).

A crude version to get the output using base R is given below

```
# get a list of offspring for each father id
foffspring <- by(indata, indata$fid, function(i) { i$id }, simplify=FALSE) 
# and mother id
moffspring <- by(indata, indata$mid, function(i) { i$id }, simplify=FALSE)
```

To get the siblings run through each id. Find their father and mother and combine the two relevant entries from the previous lists

```
sibs <- sapply( 1:nrow(indata), function(i) {
    res <- c()
    if( !is.na(indata$fid[i]) ) 
        res <- c(res, unlist(foffspring[paste0(indata$fid[i])]))
    if( !is.na(indata$mid[i]) ) 
        res <- c(res, unlist(moffspring[paste0(indata$mid[i])]))
    unique(res[res != indata$id[i]]) 
    }, simplify=TRUE )
```

This produces

```
> sibs
[[1]]
integer(0)

[[2]]
integer(0)

[[3]]
[1] 4

[[4]]
[1] 3

[[5]]
[1] 13 14

[[6]]
[1] 14 15 12

[[7]]
[1] 13 15 12

[[8]]
[1] 13 14
```

which was the desired output. Now the code above is not fast or pretty and I'd really like to see if I could get a fancy `data.table` version. However, my `data.table`-fu appears to be lacking.

```
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(indata)
# Create lists with the _indices_ of the offsprings
FT <- DT[ , list( yidx = list(.I) ) , by = fid ]
MT <- DT[ , list( yidx = list(.I) ) , by = mid ]
```

`MT` looks like this

```
   mid  yidx
1:  NA     2
2:   0     1
3:   2   3,4
4:   6 5,6,7
5:   8     8
```

Exactly like `moffspring` above except it contains the indices and not the labels. That, however, is not really a problem. Then I'd like to merge the tables together

```
setkey(DT, fid)
setkey(FT, fid)
setkey(MT, mid)

# Inner join
P1 <- DT[FT]

# And inner join on mother
setkey(P1, mid)
P1[MT]
```

and now the end result looks like this

```
   id fid mid  yidx i.yidx
1:  2   9  NA     2      2
2:  1  NA   0     1      1
3:  3   1   2   3,4    3,4
4:  4   1   2   3,4    3,4
5: 13   5   6 6,7,8  5,6,7
6: 14   5   6 6,7,8  5,6,7
7: 12   7   6     5  5,6,7
8: 15   5   8 6,7,8      8
```

This is *almost* there. Now if I take the row-wise union of `yidx` and `i.yidx` then I get the list of half-sibs (including the person self), and a row-wise intersection would yield the full siblings. Note that the indices here refer to the index in `DT` and not in the final `data.table` but that can be fixed as well.

However, ... I have a nagging feeling that something like this could be done much more efficiently in a few lines of `data.table` code and a "gentle wave of a hand". Can anyone point me in the right direction?

[Sorry for the super long post]

---

Update based on the answers below. Just for the fun of it I ran the three different suggestions through `microbenchmark` to see if there would be any timing differences among the three approaches. `f1()` is the suggestion by @Frank, `f2()` is the solution given by @mtoto, and `f3` is @amatsuo_net's approach. Tried on vectors of length 1000, and here are the output

```
Unit: milliseconds
 expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq      max neval cld
 f1() 4020.8112 4387.7950 4614.7896 4498.8043 4770.1184 6837.672   100   c
 f2()  656.9575  685.7706  727.5191  710.3003  735.2832 1080.423   100 a  
 f3() 1637.8927 1706.7528 1789.1794 1739.4428 1814.7776 2403.474   100  b
```

Quite a substantial difference in approaches. I need to run it through a dataset with 7 million id's so that certainly has a noticeable impact. Thanks all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an approach using `mapply()` in combination with `setdiff()` and `union()`. After collecting the `id`'s into a list, first we exclude the current id, and then `union()` the lists from both sides:

```
setDT(indata)[,msib:=.(list(id)), by = "mid"][
  ,msibs := mapply(setdiff, msib, id)][
  ,fsib  := .(list(id)), by = "fid"][
  ,fsibs := mapply(setdiff, fsib, id)][
  ,sibs  := mapply(union, msibs, fsibs)][
  ,c("msib","msibs", "fsib", "fsibs") := NULL]
> indata
#   id fid mid     sibs
#1:  1  NA   0         
#2:  2   9  NA         
#3:  3   1   2        4
#4:  4   1   2        3
#5: 12   7   6    13,14
#6: 13   5   6 12,14,15
#7: 14   5   6 12,13,15
#8: 15   5   8    13,14
```

Comment: Great solution. And surprisingly fast!

Answer (score 2):

I would hold back on list columns as long as possible.

Starting with siblings, here's a simple approach:

```
sibDT = DT[!is.na(fid) & !is.na(mid), 
  CJ(id = id, sid = id)[id != sid]
, by=.(fid, mid)]

#    fid mid id sid
# 1:   1   2  3   4
# 2:   1   2  4   3
# 3:   5   6 13  14
# 4:   5   6 14  13
```

And then define half siblings as sharing a parent but not appearing in `sibDT`:

```
hsibDT = melt(DT, id = "id")[!is.na(value), 
  CJ(id = id, hsid = id)[id != hsid]
, by=.(ptype = variable, pid = value)][!sibDT, on=.(id, hsid = sid)]

#    ptype pid id hsid
# 1:   fid   5 13   15
# 2:   fid   5 14   15
# 3:   fid   5 15   13
# 4:   fid   5 15   14
# 5:   mid   6 12   13
# 6:   mid   6 12   14
# 7:   mid   6 13   12
# 8:   mid   6 14   12
```

---

I would stop here, but to browse the results with a list or character column...

```
DT[sibDT[, .(sibs = toString(sid)), by=id], on=.(id), sibs := i.sibs, by=.EACHI ]
DT[hsibDT[, .(hsibs = toString(hsid)), by=id], on=.(id), hsibs := i.hsibs, by=.EACHI ]

# or...

DT[
  rbind(sibDT[, .(id, oid = sid)], hsibDT[, .(id, oid = hsid)])[, 
    .(asibs = toString(oid))
  , by=.(id)], 
  on = .(id),
  asibs := i.asibs
, by = .EACHI]
```

which gives

```
   id fid mid sibs  hsibs      asibs
1:  1  NA   0   NA     NA         NA
2:  2   9  NA   NA     NA         NA
3:  3   1   2    4     NA          4
4:  4   1   2    3     NA          3
5: 12   7   6   NA 13, 14     13, 14
6: 13   5   6   14 15, 12 14, 15, 12
7: 14   5   6   13 15, 12 13, 15, 12
8: 15   5   8   NA 13, 14     13, 14
```

Adding these columns to `DT` is counterproductive unless your analysis is complete. I guess any useful analysis would be on the non-list columns contained in the various tables.

Comment: I couldn't agree more on keeping the lists of the the data table. I'm a bit surprised this approach isn't the fastest. Love it how everything was included in just about a single line of code!

Answer (score 1):

I would do with something like this.

```
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)
setDT(indata)
tmp <- merge(indata, indata[, 1:2], by = "fid", allow.cartesian = TRUE)
tmp2 <- merge(indata, indata, by = "mid", allow.cartesian = TRUE)
tmp3 <- rbindlist(list(tmp,tmp2), fill = T)
dt_siblings <- tmp3[id.x != id.y, unique(id.y) %>% sort() %>% paste(collapse = ", "), by = id.x][order(id.x)]
setnames(dt_siblings, 'id.x', 'id')
setnames(dt_siblings, 'V1', 'siblings')
outdata <- merge(indata, dt_siblings, all.x = T)
```

The idea is to merge `indata` with `indata` by `fid` and `mid` then `rbindlist` them. The column `id.y` in `tmp3` is the id of siblings (with duplicates because of full siblings). In the next line, remove the duplicate, sort, and then concatenate. The output looks like this:

```
> outdata
   id fid mid   siblings
1:  1  NA   0         NA
2:  2   9  NA         NA
3:  3   1   2          4
4:  4   1   2          3
5: 12   7   6     13, 14
6: 13   5   6 12, 14, 15
7: 14   5   6 12, 13, 15
8: 15   5   8     13, 14
```